# ¿Cómo comprobar un objeto vacío? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
var obj = {};

if (obj != null) {
    //execute
}
```

El problema es que `obj` no es nulo.

¿Como puedo saber si es un objeto esta vacío para que entre en una condición o no?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Con **`ES5`**: [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys)

```js
let obj = {};

console.log( Object.keys(obj).length === 0 )
```

Con **`jQuery`**: [`jQuery.isEmptyObject()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/)

```js
let obj = {};

console.log( $.isEmptyObject(obj) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: no bastaria con comparar con !=null?

Comment: @x-rw - [Nop](http://jsbin.com/bohoxav/edit?html,js,console).... explicación-> Con `{}` estás iniciando/creando un objeto _vacio_ pero cual no es `null` -> [+ info](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Answer (score 9):

la respuesta de @aldanux es la acertada pero una opcion es volviendolo cadena `JSON.stringify(obj)`

```js
var obj = {};

if (JSON.stringify(obj)=='{}') {
    //execute
    console.log('vacio');
}
```

tambien podemos emplear `Object.entries(obj).`

```js
var obj = {};

if (Object.entries(obj).length === 0) {
  //execute
  console.log('vacio');
}
```

Comment: A mi me funciona la sengunda :) Saludos @x-rw

Answer (score 0):

Sugiero utilizar Lodash.
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEmpty

```
_.isEmpty(null);
// => true
 
_.isEmpty(true);
// => true
 
_.isEmpty(1);
// => true
 
_.isEmpty([1, 2, 3]);
// => false
 
_.isEmpty({ 'a': 1 });
// => false
```

Answer (score 0):

- Usando [obj.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```js
function objetoVacio(obj) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(objetoVacio({}));
console.log(objetoVacio({hola: 'mundo'}));
```

- Usando [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

```js
function objetoVacio(obj) {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length === 0;
}
console.log(objetoVacio({}));
console.log(objetoVacio({hola: 'mundo'}));
```